# Renaming multiple files by matching variable words in a directory

Tags: command-line, files, rename

I've multiple files in a directory and I want to rename it and only remove matching words from the file name.

Example files:

```
8 - build a php mvc application - finished (part 8_9).mp4
9 - build a php mvc application - database (part 9_9).mkv
```

These two files with different extensions and matching parts the I want to delete.

I want to delete this part `(part 9_9)` whatever the number in theirs.

Comment: so is this "anything within `(...)` just before the dot-end-of-filename bit, or... ?

Comment: Post with sample input  and sample output for better understandinh

Comment: I want to delete anything in ( ... ) including the parenthesis just before the dot-end-file-name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the string `(part 8_9)` but for any pair of numbers, you can use the `rename` command (sometimes known as `prename`):

```
rename -n 's/\s*\(part \d+_\d+\)//' *part*
```

This version also removes any whitespace immediately before the pattern, which although you didn't request makes the filenames look better. Omit the leading `\s*` from the pattern if you really don't want this action.

Change the "show me what would happen" flag `-n` to `-v` or even remove it entirely when you're sure it's working as expected.

---

Note that there are two similar but different commands called `rename`. The one I'm using here identifies itself like this:

```
rename
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't make any changes to the files, even no error message!

Comment: @kfathy194 read the paragraph starting with "Change..."